# Adding FIELDS on mySQL database without visiting phpMyadmin

Tags: php, mysql

i want to  create database with a  intity name "insert" but  have a only one FIELD name-->   "ID_no"  <-- (this is auto increment field)

then .. i want to use PHP codes to add a FIELD without visiting the phpMyadmin

example:

i create  my database name "data" and the intity name is "insert"

FIELD

ID_no |

then i will  the use the php output code which functions of ADDING FIELDS in mySQL database  to add a fields On my database..

PLEASE SHARE YOUR SOURCE CODE.....

Comment: _"PLEASE SHARE YOUR SOURCE CODE"_ How about.... no? No research effort at all, google is your friend.

Comment: Start from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table-examples.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to write an ALTER TABLE.. query, and then execute this in the ususal way.  eg:

```
ALTER TABLE <tablename> ADD COLUMN <columnname> <columntype>;
```

replacing the values in < >